# How to do a double summation?

Tags: r

There are two summations I am trying to complete:

[image: summations]

I need to use outer() in order to solve them and I'm stumped. I've tried solving it with cumsum() as well but it produced an array and I need one answer. Thanks!

This is what i've tried:

```
i <- 1:10
j <- 1:5
l <- cumsum(i^5/(10+j^i))
sum(outer(l))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're referring to code that you've tried, but we can't see it to help debug it

Comment: You need `outer()` to get all combinations of `i` and `j`. Your use of `cumsum()` relies on vector recycling which doesn't do all pairwise combinations. Try something like this instead: `sum(outer(1:10, 1:5, function(i,j) i^5/(10+j^i)))`

Comment: and for the second one use `sum(outer(1:10, 1:10, function(i, j)  (j <= i) * (i^5/(10+j^i))))`